# Editable gridview control using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Is there any way I can copy data from excel and paste into asp.net gridview. I also want to be able to manually edit data in this control. If not possible, what could be the possible alternative.

Comment: there are some 'not free' controls that acts like spreadsheet, but a good alternative would be importing and exporting from excel files.

Comment: thank you for suggestion. unfortunately importing and exporting will not work for me :)